# Woocommerce - How to hide the "pay button url" on the 'my account order' page for selected payment gateway. Example: show pay button only for paypal

Tags: woocommerce

I have 2 WooCommerce problems

1. Under my-account, orders: I would like to hide the payment button for certain payment methods.
   For example, only visible for paypal.
2. In the order email is also a "pay link" integrated.
   Here also make visible only for paypal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you just want to show it only for PayPal why do not just disable the other payment methods?